# How to set same transaction number if there is same time stamp in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame

[image: dataframe]

if time stamp of an instance is same with the time stamp of a second instance, I need to create a new column and set the same transaction number for both instances

I have tried using np.where and isin but I was only able to set two values

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to get an id per group:

```
df['number'] = df.groupby(['name', 'timestamp']).ngroup()
```